# angular directive reference like wikipedia

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using angularJs for creating articles with references similar to Wikipedia.

I'm thinking that it should be directive defined like:

```
<ref link="http://example.com" description="Reference description"/>
```

and then provide function somehow to count all the references in the page and have it in an array so I can show all the references at the end of the article serialised.

so the output will be like:

This is a text area [1] with some more text [2],

### References:

[1] reference link: reference description

[2] reference link: reference description

Comment: this question sounds like "_write code for me_" ..

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. If you know of a directive that is close to having this functionality, then just a link would suffice. I was googling this and didn't find anything and thought it would also be useful for others.